# Force Refresh page in Firefox 57.0.1

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Before the most recent Firefox update (Quantum, 57.0.1) I was able to refresh a page, including the cache, by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> rather than simply <kbd>F5</kbd>. This is no longer the case. Now, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> opens the page inspector, same as pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Does anyone know what the new force refresh shortcut is? I looked through the *Web Developer* tools in Firefox but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Force refresh has always been <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> is used to run the Profiler

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_navigation

Answer (score 3):

It's been <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> for as long as I can remember.